# Dropdown with multiple selection limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I relatively new to `React` and `Semantic UI` as well.
There is a component called `Dropdown` with a props `multiple` and `selection`, which allows to select multiple items.

On the output my state looks like this:

```
const selectedItems = [
   {key: 1, value: 1, text: 'Item 1'},
   {key: 2, value: 2, text: 'Item 2'},
   {key: 3, value: 3, text: 'Item 3'},
];
```

How can I do setup limit of N amount of elements?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according to https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown#dropdown-example-multiple-selection you need to create controlled component, which means you will bind `value={this.state.selectedItems}` then you will bind `onChange={(e,data) => { this.handleChange(e,data )}` and in your code

```
onChange (e, data) {
  const currentItems = this.state.selectedItems

  if (currentItems.length <= MAX_SELECTION ) {
    currentItems.push(data)

    this.setState({
      selectedItems: currentItems
    })
  }
}
```

this will crate controlled component which will allows you to control state by yourself, and you will limit changing state, probably you will need to also handle removing items from state inside this onChange event.

Comment: pretty  good solution. definitely worth a shot. I will notify you if that works well

Comment: @Reborn I modified my answer I forgot that push will return length no new array, so you will just call push to currentItems and set it as new value, sorry

Answer (score 2):

The `Semantic UI React` Dropdown option provides a function called as `onAddItem`. You will have to use the `value` data key and do  something like this:

```
const onAddItem = (event, data) => {

    1.Fetch the state of the selected values, stored in the value key
    2. Check if the limit is greater than 2
    3. If the condition is met, then add
    4. Else, show an error

}
```

[Documentation Link](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown#dropdown-example-multiple-selection)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest another approach.
set useState directly to the dropdown value.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const MAX_FRUITS_SELECTION = 3;

const FruitsSelect = () => {
  const [fruitId, setFruitId] = useState([]);

  const optionsFRUITSFake = [
    { key: 1, value: 1, text: 'Orange' },
    { key: 2, value: 2, text: 'Lemon' },
    { key: 3, value: 3, text: 'Apple' },
    { key: 4, value: 4, text: 'Banana' },
    { key: 5, value: 5, text: 'Melon' },
    { key: 6, value: 6, text: 'Pineapple' }
  ];

  const handleDropFilterFruit = (e: any, data?: any) => {
    if (data.value.length <= MAX_FRUITS_SELECTION) {
      setFruitId(data.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown
      placeholder="Select Fruits"
      onChange={handleDropFilterFruit}
      value={fruitId}
      fluid
      multiple
      selectOnNavigation={false}
      search
      selection
      options={optionsFRUITSFake}
    />
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <FruitsSelect />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That solution will also work pretty well, however, at the time of asking React didn't had Context API and hooks implemented.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Elegant and easy. It extends itself easy to using the onChange property to call a function for further logic:
'onChange={handleSelection}'

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my workaround here. It's probably more short and simple.

At first, save the values in the state (preferably redux state) after every onChange. React state also would do fine. Then, make it disabled when a certain array length of the value is reached.

```js
const districtData = ['Dhaka', 'Bagerhat', 'Bandarban', 
'Barguna', 'Barishal', 'Bhola']

const [districtValue, setDistrictValue] = useState();

<Dropdown
onChange={async (e, { name, value }) => {setDistrictValue(value)}}
options={districtData.map((currentValue, index) => {
    return {
    key: `${currentValue}`,
    value: `${currentValue}`,
    text: `${currentValue}`,
    disabled: districtValue.length > 2 ? true : false 
}
// Do other things here
// Max 3 values here, then options will be disabled. 
// Will be live again if any selected options are less than 3 here                

/>
```