# ReactJS/Semantic-UI DropDown MaxSelection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Well, I searched a lot but nothing found, I decided to solve it on my own but stuck in middle it. Let me explain first, There is an option for limit selection in `Semantic-Ui` but not in `React` version, [here](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings) you can find `maxSelections` in `Multiple Select Settings` section, but there is no such option for [reactjs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) version, and if you use this option `maxselections` nothing happen:

```
<Dropdown placeholder='Skills' fluid multiple selection options={options} maxselections={2} />
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690980/dropdown-multiple-selection-with-limitation) is a similar question asked, but it's not working at all and looks not user friendly, and just make selected into an array but what I want is stop selecting user and at least get a small error. Actually I looking something like [this](https://select2.org/selections#limiting-the-number-of-selections).

So let's see what I tried so far:

Here is default data from `json`:

```
const data = {
    options: [
        {id: 1, name: "example1"},
        {id: 2, name: "example2"},
        {id: 3, name: "example3"},
        {id: 4, name: "example4"},
        {id: 5, name: "example5"}
    ]
};

const option = data.options.map((obj) => ({
    key: obj.id,
    text: obj.name,
    value: obj.name
}));
```

Here is `state`:

```
this.state = {
    limit: false,
    selectOption: option
};
```

And this is handler:

```
getSelected  = (e, {value}) => {

const selectedOption = []

for(let i=1;value.length> i;i++){
    selectedOption.push({id: i, name: value[i]});
}

const fake = selectedOption.map((obj) => ({
    key: obj.id,
    text: obj.name,
    value: obj.name
}));

if(value.length === 2) {
    this.setState({
        limit: true,
        selectOption: fake
    })
} else {
        this.setState({
            limit: false,
            selectOption: option
        }) 
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
  <Dropdown placeholder='Skills' fluid multiple selection options={this.state.selectOption} onChange={this.getSelected} closeOnChange={this.state.limit ? true : false}/>
```

The logic is, if user reach to maximum selected, close dropdown then just show selected value in dropdown, then if less than show default options again. I'm not resist to this logic, maybe this is not a good practice for do this, if you have any idea please let me know. But in current code the problem is, options={options} update with just one selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself and decided to post it as answer for other peoples in future. I removed `for` loop and also `map` and used `forEach` and this working good:

```
getSelected  = (e, {value}) => {

const selectedOption = []

value.forEach(function(v, i) {
    selectedOption.push({key: i, text: v, value: v});
});

if(value.length === 2) {
alert('You can only select 2 options') //show error

    this.setState({
        limit: true,
        selectOption: selectedOption
    })
} else {
    this.setState({
        limit: false,
        selectOption: option
    })
}
}
```

If anyone use `id` in `value` instead of `text` go with this:

```
getSelected  = (e, data) => {
...

data.value.forEach(function(i) {
    const opt = data.options.find(o => o.value === i);
    selectedOption.push({key: i, text: opt.text, value: i});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old issue. But I'm posting my workaround here. It's short and simple.

At first, save the values in the state (preferably redux state) after every onChange. React state also would do fine. Then, make it disabled when a certain array length of the value is reached.

```js
const districtData = ['Dhaka', 'Bagerhat', 'Bandarban', 
'Barguna', 'Barishal', 'Bhola']

const [districtValue, setDistrictValue] = useState();

<Dropdown
onChange={async (e, { name, value }) => {setDistrictValue(value)}}
options={districtData.map((currentValue, index) => {
    return {
    key: `${currentValue}`,
    value: `${currentValue}`,
    text: `${currentValue}`,
    disabled: districtValue.length > 2 ? true : false 
}
// Do other things here
// Max 3 values here, then options will be disabled. 
// Will be live again if any selected option is less than 3                 

/>
```